# Замена слова на знак пунктуации

Tags: java, android-gradle

Нужен алгоритм, который в тексте заменит все слова, которые подходят под описание знака пункутации. Но если поставлена точка, то следующее предложение следует начать с большой буквы.

Например:

```
Стихотворный текст кома в отличие от простого текста точка
```

```
Стихотворный текст, в отличие от простого текста.
```

(учитывать пробелы)

```
String text = "Стихотворный текст кома в отличие от простого текста точка";

text=text.repalceAll(" кома",",").replaceAll("точка", ".");
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код, который вы пытались написать.

Comment: Например: 
Стихотворный текст кома в отличие от простого текста точка
Стихотворный текст, в отличие от простого текста.
(учитывать пробелы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать функцию, которая будет производить след. букву после слова `точка` в верхний регистр

```
String s = "Стихотворный текст кома в отличие от простого текста точка стихотворный текст точка ";
System.out.println(replaceDot(s).replace(" кома ", ", ").trim());
...
public static String replaceDot(String s) {
    String[] array = s.split(" точка");
    String result = "";
    for(String r : array) {
      if(!r.trim().isEmpty()) {
        String s1 = r.trim().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        result += s1 + r.trim().substring(1) + ". ";
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

А можно вместо функции воспользоваться регуляркой (`java.util.regex.Pattern`), опять же что бы след. букву после слова `точка` произвести в верхний регистр

```
String text = "Стихотворный текст кома в отличие от простого текста точка cтихотворный текст точка ";
String regex = "(?<=\\sточка) ?\\S";
text = Pattern.compile(regex)
    .matcher(text)
    .replaceAll(matche -> matche.group().toUpperCase());
System.out.println(text.replace(" кома ", ", ").replace(" точка ", ". ").trim());
```

И там, и там [получим](https://onecompiler.com/java/3w9dkaxdc)

```
Стихотворный текст, в отличие от простого текста. Cтихотворный текст.
```